# Why TFS Merge merges all files although they have not been changed

Tags: tfs, merge

I have Dev and Release Branches in tfs.

I use release branch only for critical fixes after I release a version

Before each release I want to overwrite all changes made in Release branch with Dev branch. After that Release and Dev branches should be equal.

I'm using following commands to do so:

```
tf merge DEV RELEASE -r -force -version:1~T -noprompt
tf resolve RELEASE -r -auto:acceptTheirs
```

The problem is, that all files are in pending changes with "merge" change. I also see this in tfs history of file after check in.

Is this correct approach?  Should I do things differently, e.g check in only changesets from last release? does it have any side effects?

Comment: Why use the command line?

Comment: The -force param forces all files to merge regardless of changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the -force parameter. That is the result of that c command.

"Ignores the merge history and merges the specified changes from the source into the destination, even if some or all these changes have been merged before"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(v=vs.100).aspx

If you remove the -force option it will only merge the changes.

Comment: If I remove force option, can I ensure, that the release branch will be the same as dev branch? All changes in release branch must be overwritten by last dev sources, even if dev has not been changed since last merge

Comment: You cant have it both ways. You either merge normally, like everyone else. Or you use the -force option and it ignores the history of previous merges. As long as you have always had a branch relationship, or have previously at least once used -force or done a baseless merge, you can just do a normal merge and all the changes from the last merge will go across.